# How to get "," instead of "and" in the rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table Test with 1 column

```
Module_name

Table  
Computer  
Laptop  
Chair
```

My expected output:

```
Table,Computer,Laptop and Chair
```

My Query:

```
declare @module_name varchar(50)
SELECT @Module_Name = COALESCE(@Module_Name + ' and ', '') + module_name FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT module_name FROM Test) T       
    select @module_name
```

I am getting the output as:

```
Table and Computer and Laptop and Chair
```

My concern is how to get the "," instead of "and".

Comment: "Grammarisation" should be done in your presentation layer, not by your data engine.

Comment: Although there's a nasty way to modify your current code to *maybe* produce the output you're looking for, be aware that your current technique is [flawed anyway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks): "Do not use a variable in a SELECT statement to concatenate values (...). Unexpected query results may occur. This is because all expressions in the SELECT list (...) are not guaranteed to be executed exactly once for each output row"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried *xml* method with `stuff()` function ?

```
declare @Module_names varchar(max)

set @Module_names = stuff((select distinct ',' +Module_name 
                           from table t
                           for xml path('')),1,1, '')  
select REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(@Module_names),                
                    CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@Module_names)), 1,' dna ')) as Module_names
```

Comment: And how would that give the desired output?

Comment: I believe he wants values separated by comma until the last one, which should be "and".

Comment: I agree, this is a **MUCH** better technique than a nasty self referencing variable, however, the OP wants `' and '` between the penultimate and final value; it's not a simple delimited list. They want to `Grammarise" the data, not delimit it.

Comment: It is comma separated output without And.

Comment: It is still giving me an error.Msg 189, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
The charindex function requires 2 to 3 arguments.

Comment: @RedDevil... It was Typo Corrected.

Comment: Now your query is running fine. But if my table have only single entry it is showing blank.

Answer (score 1):

I don't endorse this solution, like I said in the comments, **"grammarisation" should be done in your presentation layer.**. You can, however, achieve this in SQL like so:

*Edit: Slight update to cater for a single value return.*

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample (Module varchar(10));

INSERT INTO #Sample
VALUES ('Table'),
       ('Computer'),
       ('Laptop'),
       ('Chair');
GO
WITH RNs AS (
    SELECT Module,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN --SELECT NULL as there is no ID field to work with here, thus the order will be random
    FROM #Sample)
SELECT STUFF((SELECT CASE WHEN RN = MAX(RN) OVER () AND RN != 1 THEN ' and ' ELSE ', ' END + Module
              FROM RNs
              ORDER BY RN
              FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'');

GO

DROP TABLE #Sample;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following. First gather all records together with comma, then replace just the last one with "and". Will have to make sure that your column values don't contain comma or it will be misplaced with an "and" if on last occurence.

```
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF(
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            ', ' + T.module_name
        FROM
            Test AS T
        FOR XML
            PATH('')
    ),
    1, 2, '')


SET @result = 
    REVERSE(
        STUFF(                                  -- Replace
            REVERSE(@result),                   -- ... in the reversed string
            CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@result)),   -- ... at the first position of the comma (the last one on the original string)
            1,                                  -- just 1 character (the comma)
            'dna ')                             -- for the reversed " and"
        )

SELECT @result
```

Answer (score 0):

Used Row_number to capture last row,

```
CREATE TABLE test
    ([Module_name] varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO test
    ([Module_name])
VALUES
    ('Table'),
    ('Computer'),
    ('Laptop'),
    ('Chair')
;

 SELECT STUFF((SELECT CASE WHEN RN = MAX(RN) OVER () THEN ' and ' ELSE ', ' END + Module_name
    from 
    (

        SELECT Module_name,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN 
        FROM test
    ) rns

    ORDER BY RN
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'');
```